# gatsby-remark-images-remote make the build fail, how to troubleshoot the root cause?

Tags: gatsby, sharp, gatsby-image, gatsby-remark-image

My gatsby site https://jeff-tian.jiwai.win/ (Source code: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/space/) uses gatsby js. It contains thousands of markdown blog posts and the building used to be smooth before I made the following change.

The images in the posts couldn't be rendered directly as they are remote images.

So I think I can download the images locally during the building phase, and found this plugin just for the purpose: https://github.com/icaraps/gatsby-remark-images-remote.

However, when met the broken link it throws. So I forked the plugin to catch the errors regarding broken links and continue building the site.

But the building still fails and I don't know why. I tried many tweaks for example configuring `failOn` to `none` to the `image-sharp` plugin.

[image]

Still no luck. You can check the failed jobs here: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/space/actions

[image]

There are error logs, however, they shouldn't block the building. The error is something similar to   `Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format`.
[image]

Could anyone help me troubleshoot the root cause? Is there any option from the gatsby configuration side to continue building along with these image-processing errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took a deep breath and started to write test cases to try to reproduce the error:

[image]

And succeeded in reproducing with the latest test case, and then by following the error trace locally I finally spotted the devil!

The `gatsby-plugin-sharp` has a line of code: `process.exit(1)`. Damn!!

After the root cause founded, I created a PR to fix it: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/37165.

[image]